# _OBJC_CLASS_$_OALSuspendHandler Linking Error in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I believe the error is due to AVAudioPlayer() or OALSimpleAudio.sharedInstance() ? It also may be due to not having a certain framework installed or maybe this audio framework was deprecated?

```
 I am getting this error:


 "_OBJC_CLASS_$_OALSuspendHandler", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libcocos2d.a(ALDevice.o)
      objc-class-ref in libcocos2d.a(ALSource.o)
      objc-class-ref in libcocos2d.a(OALAudioTrack.o)
      objc-class-ref in libcocos2d.a(OALAudioTracks.o)
      objc-class-ref in libcocos2d.a(ALContext.o)
      objc-class-ref in libcocos2d.a(OpenALManager.o)
      objc-class-ref in libcocos2d.a(ALListener.o)
      ...
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Comment: Have you added `AVFoundation.framework` to your project?

Comment: @Lawliet No I just aded the framework, I just cleaned and built my project and I still receive the error... thanks for the help